# Is it possible to reorder Kendo Tabstrip tabs with drag and drop?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-tabstrip

Is is possible to reorder the tabs with drag and drop (see Kendo Tabstrip basic mode [here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/tabstrip/index))? Similar to dragging tabs in Excel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a solved question similar to this on [kendo forum](http://www.telerik.com/forums/reorderable-tabstrip---applying-droptargets-to-new-tabs), it already has the answer to solve this problem by extending the **kendo tabstrip widget** and add **kendo Reorderable** into it.

```
var numTabs = 1, tabs = null;

var reorderableTabStrip = kendo.ui.TabStrip.extend({
    options: {
        name: 'ReorderableTabStrip'
    },

    init: function ( element, options ) {
        kendo.ui.TabStrip.fn.init.call(this, element, options);
        this.applyReorderable();
    },

    applyReorderable: function () {
        var reorderable = this.tabGroup.data('kendoReorderable');
        if ( reorderable ) {
          reorderable.destroy();
        }

        this.tabGroup.kendoReorderable({
            group: 'tabs',
            filter:'.k-item',
            hint: function(element) {
                return element.clone().wrap('<ul class="k-tabstrip-items k-reset"/>').parent().css({opacity: 0.8});
            },
            change: $.proxy(this.onReorderableChange, this)
        });
    },

    onReorderableChange: function ( event ) {
        if ( event.newIndex < event.oldIndex ) {
            this.tabGroup.children('.k-item:eq('+event.newIndex+')').before( this.tabGroup.children('.k-item:eq('+event.oldIndex+')') );
            this.element.children('.k-content:eq('+event.newIndex+')').before( this.element.children('.k-content:eq('+event.oldIndex+')') );
        }
        else {
            this.tabGroup.children('.k-item:eq('+event.newIndex+')').after( this.tabGroup.children('.k-item:eq('+event.oldIndex+')') );
            this.element.children('.k-content:eq('+event.newIndex+')').after( this.element.children('.k-content:eq('+event.oldIndex+')') );
        }
        this._updateClasses();
    }
});
kendo.ui.plugin( reorderableTabStrip );

tabs = $('#tabs').kendoReorderableTabStrip().data('kendoReorderableTabStrip');

$('#button').click( onButtonClick );

function onButtonClick () {
    numTabs++;
    tabs.append({
        text: 'Tab ' + numTabs,
        content: 'Tab ' + numTabs + ' Content'
    });
    tabs.applyReorderable();
}
```

I follow the answer there and modify the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/machun/rf9y74qc/) by the one who asked the question and it's work fine.